# Refactor method and remove extra local variable(remove binding)

Tags: java, methods, refactoring

I have this class:

```java
public class User {
    private String name;
    private int age;
    //getters setters
}
```

I have a method, which updates a user object:

```java
public void foo(User user) { 
    boolean needUpdate = false;
    
    if(needUpdateName(user.getName())) {
        user.setName("new name"); 
        needUpdate = true;
    }
    
    if(needUpdateAge(user.getAge())) {
        user.setAge(42);
        needUpdate = true; 
    }
    
    if(needUpdate) {
        userRepository.update(user);
    } 
}
```

It's a simple example, only as an example. How can I refactor this code and remove `needUpdate` variable?

Comment: You could make a list of "updater"s (each returns whether they did something) and reduce it to a `boolean`

Comment: I think the variable should be moved to inside the User class - it can keep state to know if it needs updating to the repo. That is how Hibernate works. Maybe you should just use Hibernate rather than reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

Just split `Foo` to two methods

```java
public void updateNameIfNeed(User user) {
    if (needUpdateName(user.getName())) {
       user.setName("new name"); 
       userRepository.update(user);
    }
}

public void updateAgeIfNeed(User user) {
    if (needUpdateAge(user.getAge())) {
        user.setAge(42);
        userRepository.update(user);
    }
}
```